# How to queue the post request in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Current post request:

```
app.post('/rImage', rawBody, function (req, res) {
// ---- check here, if this process is running ? ----
  var data = req.rawBody;
  var escapedData = data.replace(/([<>|&^])/g, "\^$1"); // Windows CMD escaping
  exec('cscript /nologo C:/PS/Automation/render.vbs C:/PS/Automation/image.jsx"'+escapedData + '"',
    function (error, stdout, stderr)  {
      console.log('stdout: ' + escapedData);

      if(error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
      }
      res.send(stdout);
      //request finished
    });
});
```

How could I implement a queue system to this, so that the next request fires off when the last one is finished?

Thanks in adnvance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be libraries for this. However, you could hack it like this:

```
var queue = [];
var active = false;
var check = function() {
   if (!active && queue.length > 0) {
      var f = queue.shift();
      f();
   }
}

app.post("..", body, function(req, res) {
   queue.push(function() {
      active = true;

      exec("yourprogram arg1 arg2..", function() {
          // this is the async callback
          active = false;
          check();
      });
   });
   check();
});
```

Here's a fiddle that shows the functionality: https://jsfiddle.net/fc15afw5/1/

Comment: +1 for a "poor man's queue". As for libraries, try [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue). You could also do something a little more infrastructure based, like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Comment: The async library looks very interesting, didn't know this before. But if it would come to a direct implementation, what would you improve in the code above? - in order to make it a bit more a rich man's queue ;-)

Comment: Depends on what we're doing, why we're queueing it, if we need to scale it up, etc. :) Looking at it again, it seems we're executing some VBScript? In that case, I don't think I'd change a thing, as it looks like we just want to make sure the script only executes one at a time (I'd assume because the VBScript will break if run concurrently). If we wanted flexibility when it comes to the number of concurrent runs, I might reach for async.queue. If it's some kind of slow processing we could offload to another server, I might use RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thanks! This works exactly as needed! @tanner-faulkner : yes, the VBScript will break on concurrent runs and in the future there might be a need for a load balancer.